# Obtener map de distintos select

Tags: jquery

Buenas tardes estoy creando un formulario, en el cual una parte de el esta construida por filas, cada fila incluye, dos inputs y un select, partimos de una fila.

```
<div class="row" style="position:relative;" >
  <div class="col-6">
    <label class="labelMinis">Nombre del producto</label>
       <input type="text" name="name_producto[]" id="producto_1" value="" class="form-control inputMinis" placeholder="ejmp: Dragon hecho por mi">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="labelMinis">Estado del producto</label>
       <select class="form-control inputMinis" name="estado_producto[]" id="producto_1" style="overflow: hidden;">
          <option value="En matriz">En matriz</option>
          <option value="Montado">Montado</option>
          <option value="Chusta">Chusta</option>
          <option value="Conver">Conver</option>
       </select>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="labelMinis">Und</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control inputMinis" name="cantidad_producto[]" id="producto_1" min="1" value="1">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

El usuario puede ir añadiendo filas si quiere añadir más contenido, cada fila que se genera por jquery contiene lo mismo, dos inputs y un select.

*Omito el código jquery para generer más filas por que al final hace un `append` del mismo contenido html que hay construido diferenciados por una id incrementable que tiene cada uno.*

Bien también tiene el formulario un drag & drop para que pueda subir fotografias, entonces esta libreria me obliga a mandar los datos como los expongo, es [dropzone](https://docs.dropzone.dev/)

Bien los inputs, ya sea uno o 10 los envio así:

```
formData.append("productos", jQuery('input[name="name_producto[]"]').map(function (idx, elem) {
  return $(elem).val();
}).get());
```

Eso hace que en mi controlador reciba los valores separados por ",".

Pero en los valores del Select, siempre recibo un `null`

```
#parameters: array:5 [
  "productos" => "fwef,fwefw"
  "estado" => null
  "cantidad" => "1,1"
  ......
]
```

Esto es lo que intento con el Select, pero recibo una respuesta de null:

```
formData.append("estado", jQuery('input[name="estado_producto[]"]').find('option').map(function (idx, elem) {
  return $(elem).val();
}).get());
```

Comment: No se comprende que es lo que quieres lograr, edita tu pregunta añadiendo mas detalle y adjunta tu código HTML.

Comment: Buenas @AntonioGalicia revisa ahora por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno al final era más facil de lo que parecia, un erro de novato.

```
formData.append("estado", jQuery('input[name="estado_producto"] option:selected').map(function (idx, elem) {
  return $(elem).val();
}).get());
```

Era correcto, pero habia que cambiar `jQuery('input...` por `jQuery('select....` quedando así:

```
formData.append("estado", jQuery('select[name="estado_producto"] option:selected').map(function (idx, elem) {
  return $(elem).val();
}).get());
```